# Convert this complete program into a list function

Tags: python

I have a program I have completed and it works but I struggle a lot with list. I want to store the grades in a list and still have the program work the same way. The python program is supposed to get students' grades, give them their individual GPAs and then output a final class overall gpa once the program is completely terminated.

```
  gpa_entire_class = 0
    count_entire_class = 0

    def GetName():
            name = raw_input ("Enter the student's name of '***' to terminate  ")
            if name == '***':
                print "PROGRAM TERMINATED ON REQUEST"
                print "The GPA for all entered grades is %.2f" %(CalcGPA(gpa_entire_class, count_entire_class))
                exit(0)
            else:
                return name

    def getgrades():
        count = 0 
        totalgpa = 0
        grade = raw_input("Enter a grade or '*' to terminate: ")
        while grade!='*':
            if grade == 'A' or grade == 'a':
                totalgpa = totalgpa + 4
                count = count + 1
            elif grade == 'B' or grade == 'b':
                totalgpa = totalgpa + 3
                count = count + 1
            elif grade == 'C' or grade == 'c':
                totalgpa = totalgpa + 2
                count = count + 1
            elif grade == 'D' or grade == 'd':
                totalgpa = totalgpa + 1
                count = count + 1
            elif grade == 'F' or grade == 'f':
                totalgpa = totalgpa + 0
                count = count + 1
            else:
                print "ILLEGAL GRADE ENTERED"
            grade = raw_input("Enter a grade or '*' to terminate: ")
        return totalgpa, count

    def CalcGPA(totalgpa,count):
            if count == 0:
                GPA = 0
            else:
                GPA = (totalgpa)*1.0/count 
            return GPA

    def main(name, GPA):
            print "The GPA for", name,"is %.2f" %(GPA)
            return 0


    while True:
        name = GetName()
        totalgpa, count = getgrades()
        GPA= CalcGPA(totalgpa, count)
        main(name, GPA)
        gpa_entire_class = gpa_entire_class + totalgpa
        count_entire_class = count_entire_class + count
```

Answer (score 0):

For grades, you could start with a `dict`:

```
grades_to_gpa = {'a': 4, 'b': 3, 'c': 2, 'd': 1, 'f': 0}
```

then in `get_gpa`

```
def get_gpa():
  gpa_list = []
  grade = raw_input("Enter a grade or '*' to terminate: ")
  while grade != '*':
    try:
      points = grades_to_gpa[grade.lower()]
      gpa_list.append(points)
    except KeyError:
      print "Illegal grade"
    grade = raw_input("Enter a grade or '*' to terminate: ")
  return gpa_list
```

and in `main`

```
 def main():
   gpa_list = get_gpa()
   try:
     avg_gpa = sum(gpa_list) / (len(gpa_list)*1.0)
   except ZeroDivisionError:
     avg_gpa = 0.0
   print avg_gpa
```

I left some parts out but I think you should get an idea to start with from this.

**Little explanation**

In line 5 of `get_gpa()` we first take the `grade` and lowercase it. So regardless of `A` or `a`, we search the dictionary with `a`. We can look up values from dictionary with `dictionary[key]` which replaces the `if-else` structure you had. Then we append that value (number from 0 to 4) to the list of all gpas.

In the main, we can then `try` to divide with the length and in case the `gpa_list` is empty, we get a `ZeroDivisionError` in which case the `avg_gpa` is 0.